# What should I put as the return value for the docblock in the Laravel 4 eloquent model class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpdoc

I have the following basic class setup:

```
class Document extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * [types description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function types() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Type');
    }

}
```

What value would be appropriate to put in the return type doc block? Doing a var dump of the return method points the object \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany

Would that be correct in this instance? (I'm not really sure why if so?)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same Laravel is using:

```
@return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
```

Take a look at the file

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns an `array` at the most basic level....though I would just call it a `Relationship`....as thats kinda self explanatory, and thats what Laravel calls it in its docblock

```
class Document extends Eloquent {

/**
 * [types description]
 * @return Relationship 
 */
public function types() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Type');
}

}
```